# How can I distribute a bookmarklet in FBML?

Tags: facebook, bookmarklet, fbml, fbjs

I have a JavaScript bookmarklet that I'd like fans of a certain page to take. Unfortunately, the only way I've found of distributing it is giving them the raw JavaScript source, which is then problematic to add as a bookmark.

Ideally, I'd use

```
<a href="javascript:/*my bookmarklet*/">Drag this to the bookmarks bar</a>
```

But FBML filters out the JavaScript href.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh. Looks like dragging the bookmarklet in text form is sufficient to create a bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not possible using fbml, I would share a link to a web page where you put the actual bookmarklet. It is the opportunity to display on this page a tutorial on how install/use the bookmarklet.